# Drupal scalabity: the main menu is too long

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7 and I have realized that I have a main menu which has about 416 links. I know that they are too much links, but there is no way to simplify it. Because of that, it is quite difficult to edit the main menu; for example, If I try to edit the menu and save it, the POST request is too long and it has some side effects: it gets filtered by Firewalls, the SQL query is too long, etc.

Currently, If I want to change the order of each link I have to edit them one by one and change their weight. So, If I want to move a section with 10 links, I have to edit the link, change its value and save it, that's about 3 click. Eventually, It would take me about 30 clicks to change them all, at least. It is really painful to do that, that is not usable.

So, is there any way or any module to fix that? For example, is there any way to paginate the links? How would you handle this problem?

Comment: 416 links? That's just crazy. Personally I would rethink my design if the main menu had that many links. Are these links automatically generated? As far as editing/ordering the menu links, I can not think of a way to simplify it (though I am a bit drunk now :) ).

Comment: I tried to split the menu into some submenus, but that wouldn't solve the problem, since they wouldn't be 400 links but they would be 100, and that isn't scalable anyways...

There is no way to remove those links since it is a really big project (and my bosses doesn't want to listen to me).

Comment: Still 100 links in a menu are too much.. Try to reduce them or place some of the menu links in the footer of the site.

Comment: I wish I could do that, but that is not possible, @samirchauhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one module called [HugeMenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/bigmenu) which was started by @dman after [this discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/1063004).

You should give it a try.

Having huge menus may slow down your Drupal instance in a lot of places, you should also have a look at the [MenuPerformance](https://www.drupal.org/project/menuperformance) module.

As a side note I'm always astonished by the lack of pagination and volume support in basic CMS graphical user interfaces in Drupal, you should never have too big taxonomies, too big menus, too much content types (the very simple default admin/content page and the awful ergonomy of the filters on this page...), too much ACL (the administrative area contains a huge table of roles*acl), too much blocks, etc.